# 200Ah battery for a 500W mini ITX PC

Tags: conversion, pc

I want to make a project that allows a 500 watt PC to run on batteries for 4 hours, so it can be worn by an individual on their back.

I found the below calculation to get the capacity of the battery needed:
(Power (Watts) / 12V) * 1.1 * 4 = total time
(500 / 12) * 1.1 * 4 = 183.3

I get 4 hours running time, however I am not sure what my options are for a battery configuration that can be worn on the back. It would be nice to have a battery pack that follows the contours of a back - but I understand that the requirements rule that kind of flexibility.

Any guidance would be great.

**edit 1** The above doesn't include overrun to prevent 100% discharge as the decision to reduce runtime or increase capacity hasn't been weighed (pun not intended.)

The PC will be connected to a 4k VR headset running in a VR environment that would likely be graphically / processor intensive.

The purpose for it being a PC and not a laptop mobo is modularity and future proofing.

I've not decided on the battery type yet as this is just a prototype and would affect ease of setup, functionality (trickle charge or not) etc.

Comment: Your calculation does not take into account any reserve capacity. You will never want to completely exhaust the battery as that will drastically reduce its lifetime. Your PC will also not continuously use 500 Watt. What kind of battery technology are you considering?

Comment: That's a bit of an elaborate, round-about, way to impose torture on the poor soul who has to carry this 200Ah battery + PC around on their back. Surely you could achieve the same processing power (or whatever your real goal is) with a more power-efficient solution? Something like a Raspberry Pi + a USB power bank perhaps?

Comment: Can I carry a macbook air instead - a lot less than 500W...

Comment: many thanks for your comments, I have responded in edit 1

Comment: Your probably looking at a couple of kilograms of batteries alone + power gear. You might want to read https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16506/need-batteries-for-backpack-operation

Comment: The other thing you are going to run into is the computer power supply. You can't just connect the batteries to a ATX motherboards 12v supply, and high power DC-DC PC supplies are rare. Do you plan on building that yourself?

Comment: Thank you @user1937198 reading thread now

at this stage I'm just looking to get a working prototype, current intention is to use an 500w inverter but dc-dc pc do exist: http://www.pico-box.com/en/products/1682/X500

Comment: @CaptainComedy They exist, but are rare and heavy. I've worked with pico-box's products before, and expect the supply to be the heaviest single component after your batteries.

Comment: I'm guessing the item I linked above wouldn't be appropriate for my needs, what are the specs that I need to tolerate the continuous draw for my requirements?

Comment: That is probably a different question. Along with how much weight can you accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118599/discussion-between-captain-comedy-and-user1937198). I guess I can start with 50kg and add / subtract from there

Comment: with LiFePO4 you'd be looking at somewhere between 15-20kg; with Li-Ion, practically around 10kg, lead acid much more.

Comment: That's reassuring, the intention would be to evenly distribute the weight across the back but just looking at a working prototype at the moment so happy to settle on a concentrated area.

from the thread user1937198 it seems that is definitely the right way to go, from what I read li-ion is pretty dangerous for this stage

Comment: should I look at aliexpress? like this: [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001936928381.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.569690a6EuvXse&algo_pvid=8cad0a89-0762-46de-8a1f-7bc56eec97d0&algo_expid=8cad0a89-0762-46de-8a1f-7bc56eec97d0-2&btsid=2100bdde16109880596837676ebddd&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

Comment: Anything on Aliexpress or ebay or amazon or similar is suspect until tested.  Make sure you use the correct circuits and protections for charge, discharge and monitoring of any battery chemistry you intend to use.  In the case of batteries carried by humans, consideration must be given to how the battery will fail, for example lithium ion batteries must be able to vent safely in an emergency.  In a cell phone, this inflates the bag that forms the casing for the battery and pushes apart the casing of the device to show something is wrong for example.

Comment: The battery in your link has a hard shell, so you need to take into account what happens when it overpressures.  Does it have a vent point or does the casing split?  Then make sure your design protects the user in this eventuality.  Take a lot of care with your design as you're dealing with a far greater amount of battery than is dangerous to a human.